# How to work with linked script files. Testcomplete

Tags: testcomplete

Have a problem with linked files in TestComplete 9.

Model of problem:
In one project suit I have couple projects.
First project (Project_1) have all script files that are used in common. e.g. Utiles1.sj, Utiles2.sj ... etc;  Helper1.js ... Verify.js

All other project have linked script file Utiles1.sj from Project_1.
For now everything is OK.

Next, in Project1 in Utiles1.sj I used //USEUNIT Helper1 (Exists only in Project_1)

To make project lived I have linked Helper1 to all project where I need functionality from Utiles1.sj

In result when i have a lot of such project and such files I should link link link.

Is there a workaround for such case with minimum effort to spend?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your shared script units to a separate folder on the hard drive. When you need to link them to a new project, open this folder in the **Add Existing Child - Script** dialog and press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut to select all files in order to avoid adding them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
USEUNIT unitA
```

at the top of your script where you wanto import and then you can use the functions of unitA in your current script file